# jquery question - addclass to element depending on active image in rotating banner

Tags: jquery, image, rotation, addclass

**EDIT : Per Slaks**

```
$j('#banner-content img').each(function() {
    var link = $j('#page-tabs li a.' + $j(this).attr('class'));

    if ($j(this).is(':visible')) {
        link.addClass('active');
    } else {
        link.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

---

### ORIGINAL POST

I have a banner that rotates a series of three images.  The active one has a display:block, while the inactive have display:none.  I'm trying to match the class for the active image with an  tag so that I can add an "active" class to the a tag.  Having some trouble writing that function.  It's adding all of the classes for each of the img elements, regardless of whether they're being displayed or not...

The html markup looks like this:

```
<div id="banner-area">
    <div class="clearfix" id="promo-boxes-nav">
        <ul id="banner-tabs">
            <li>
                <ul id="page-tabs">
                    <li><a class="t39" href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="t42" href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="t49" href="#">3</a></li>                            
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="last">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="banner-content">
         <img class="t39" src="http://localhost:8888/1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; opacity: 0;">                                            
         <img class="t42" src="http://localhost:8888/2.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; opacity: 1;">                                            
         <img class="t49" src="http://localhost:8888/3.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;opacity: 0;">                                        
    </div>
</div>
```

The function in its current form looks like this:

```
$j('#banner-content img').each(function() {
    if($j(this).css('display','inline')) {
        var bcClass = $j(this).attr('class');

        $j('#page-tabs li a').each(function() {
            if($j('#page-tabs li a').hasClass(bcClass)) {
                $j(this).addClass(bcClass); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer for new question:

`$j(this).show()` will show the element.
You mean

```
if($j(this).is(':visible'))
```

Also, in your selectors, you want to write `$j(this)`, not `$j('#banner-content img:visible')`.

Finally, the code will be easier to read if you make a separate variable to hold the `<a>` element, like this:

```
var link = $j('#page-tabs li a.' + $j(this).attr('class'));

if ($j(this).is(':visible'))
    link.addClass('active');
else
    link.removeClass('active');
```

---

## Answer for old question:

Your problem is that you're calling `hasClass` on all of the links within the inner `each` call.  This will check whether *any* of the elements has that class, not just the current one.
You need to change it to `if($j(this).hasClass(bcClass))`.

---

However, your code is needlessly complicated, and can be written much more simply:

```
 $j('#page-tabs a.' 
        + $j('#banner-content img:visible').attr('class'))
     .addClass('active);
```

This code calls `$j('#banner-content img:visible').attr` to find the class of the visible `<img>` element, then puts the class directly into a jQuery selector.

Note that you probably also want to call `removeClass`.

Comment: Trying to incorporate this instead of mine, since it looks so much shorter and cleaner, but what I'm doing isn't working...  I'll post what I'm trying to implement in the original post...

Comment: Still not getting this, although I really appreciate the help...  I'm re-editing the original post again to reflect the changes I made per your last post...

Comment: It adds the class to the first <a> tag, but doesn't remove it or add it as the banners cycle.  It just stays as it is.  Also, there are no js errors in firebug, so can't really tell what's happening...

Comment: The code is only being run once.  You need to execute the code again each time the banner changes, using the cycle plugin's `after` callback.  (Put the `each` call in a function, then pass the function as the `after` callback and run it immediately)